# Static IP for RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, routes, amazon-rds

**I need a static IP that would point to an RDS instance** and I am not sure where to start.

I have seen these:

- [Is there a way to set a static IP on an AWS RDS Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069473/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-static-ip-on-an-aws-rds-instance)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/589140/assign-elastic-ip-to-rds-instance

But they do not answer the question or are very outdated.

I found an article that shows an example of doing this via ec2 that would route traffic to that endpoint while ec2 is having a static IP - seem like overkill.

- Article: [https://dev.to/wrschneider/ec2-proxy-to-rds-for-a-static-ip-address-11i8#:~:text=RDS%20instances%20in%20AWS%20do,different%20availability%20zone%20(AZ)](https://dev.to/wrschneider/ec2-proxy-to-rds-for-a-static-ip-address-11i8#:%7E:text=RDS%20instances%20in%20AWS%20do,different%20availability%20zone%20(AZ)).

Is there a cleaner way to do so?

I need static IP because I have a server with multiple networks behind corporate firewalls, and only 1 network interface can access RDS. Due to the lack of static IP I am unable to add it to the routing table on the server (and no, I can not do anything with the networks themselves, no I can not get IT to make all networks access RDS.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The expected way to connect to an RDS cluster is by using the fqdn.

Then I would have my internal on premise DNS aware of a private route53 zone:
https://www.tinfoilcipher.co.uk/2020/10/06/hybrid-windows-server-dns-with-aws-route-53/

Then I would alias the RDS fqdn in this route53 and have my on premise machine calling this private route53 fqdn.